# Using type in template class of derived template class

Tags: c++

Try to implement the CRTP pattern. Therefore I created two template classes. With the first draft of only one template class PDerived everything is fine. But for my purpose in a bigger project I need two template classes. Which results in an error: All types of the PDerivced class are not found. But I have no idear why. In the following the is a minimalistic example.

In this example myType can not be found? If TDerived is no template class everything is fine. Is there some namespace needed?

```
#include <iostream>

template< typename PDerived >
class TBase
{
 public:
  using myType = uint8_t;

  void Foo( void )
  {
   static_cast< PDerived* > ( this )->Bar();
  }
};

template< typename Derived > class TDerived : public TBase< TDerived<Derived> >
{
  friend class TBase< TDerived > ;
 protected:
  void Bar( void )
  {
   std::cout << "in Bar" << std::endl;
  }
 private:
  myType myVariable;

};

int main( void )
{
 TDerived<uint8_t> lD;

 lD.Foo();

 return ( 0 );
}
```

Error message:

```
error: 'myType' does not name a type
```

Comment: Move the type alias outside the first class or move it inside every class or refer to it as `TBase::myType`. Type aliases are relative to their scope. Did you mean to use `Derived` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to refer to some templated stuff of your base class, you have to give the compiler a hint how to find it.

Change your line:

```
myType myVariable;
```

to

```
TBase< TDerived<Derived> >::myType myVariable;
```

The underlying problem is, that unqualified names are not resolved during this stage until the template is fully defined. You get the same problem if you try to call member functions or variables from your base class. In this case you can simply use `this->MemberFunc()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Had to change it to `typename TBase< TDerived<Derived> >::myType myVariable;` otherwise I got the message: `error: need 'typename' before 'TBase<TDerived<Derived> >::myType' because 'TBase<TDerived<Derived> >' is a dependent scope`

Comment: if you had to add `typename` you are running an older C++-version. Current c++ standard is c++20 and there you don't need it! :-) And you question is tagged C++ and not C++17 .. :-) @AndreasBurnickl

Comment: Yes you are right using a very old version C++14 ;-)